# Como gerar um executável de um programa feito no Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, exportação

Eu fiz um programa para a empresa em que eu trabalho inteiramente em `JOptionPane`, justamente para que o programa funcionasse apenas abrindo janelas reais do sistema (pensei que seria mais fácil de rodar oficialmente depois da exportação do que um que eu visse funcionando pela caixinha de texto do Eclipse).

Meu código está 100% pronto e funcional, e o Eclipse não está indicando nenhum erro. Mas, obviamente, nenhum outro funcionário da empresa tem o Eclipse para ficar abrindo o programa por ele. Preciso que o programa possa ser aberto por qualquer computador, Windows ou Mac. Para isso, eu precisaria de uma versão do programa em .exe (para Win) e .dmg (Mac).

Pergunta 1: Como que eu crio esses executáveis? Meu sistema operacional é Mac e o Eclipse é o Neon3.

Pergunta 2: Quais vão ser os requisitos necessários para que os futuros usuários do meu software possam roda-lo? Apenas o Java instalado? Windows/Mac já vêm com os programas necessários?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Pergunta 1: Como que eu crio esses executáveis? Meu sistema operacional é Mac e o Eclipse é o Neon3.

Você pode exportar um jar do seu programa no eclipse indo em `File > Export...`, selecionando na lista a opção `Runnable JAR file`.

Na tela seguinte, você seleciona na lista a sua classe `Main` do projeto e um nome para o jar. É importante que o projeto já tenha sido executado no eclipse, senão não vai aparecer nesta lista, pois o eclipse cria algumas configurações para cada classe executada que possua um método `main`, e utiliza estas para também criar o jar.

No exemplo abaixo, estou criando um jar do meu *ProjetoTeste*, e a `ClasseMain` como a classe inicia a aplicação:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após isso, a aplicação rodará a partir do jar, através de 2 cliques. Se quiser, pode usar o [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/), que empacota o jar num *exe*, e permite que você defina vários parâmetros de personalização, como versão máxima e minima do JRE que o usuário deve ter para executar sua aplicação, decorar com um ícone, etc...

> Pergunta 2: Quais vão ser os requisitos necessários para que os futuros usuários do meu software possam roda-lo? Apenas o Java instalado? Windows/Mac já vêm com os programas necessários?

Se você incluir todas as libs de terceiros no classpath do projeto, não é mais necessário nada do usuário, a não ser possuir instalada a máquina virtual do java(JRE). Claro que ele precisa utilizar uma versão igual ou superior a que você utilizou para compilar sua aplicação.

Comment: Excelente resposta! Com certeza vou testar tudo agora... Mas como eu tenho certeza de que todas as libs de terceiros estão sendo complicadas junto? Como eu tenho certeza de que eu tô usando alguma lib de terceiro, at all? Hahaha, é que eu sou um pouco novato ainda...

Comment: @santosmarco_ olha no seu projeto se tem algo alem de `JRE System Library`. Se não, nada a preocupar, se tiver, provavelmente já estão adicionadas no classpath, e se observar a opção marcada no print em `Library handling`, a IDE já irá incluir pra você automaticamente :)

Comment: Beleza! Muito obrigado!