# Como mudar imagem do icone de inicialização de um .jar?

Tags: java, gui, jframe, icons

Por exemplo, trocar aquela xícara de café por outro ícone.

Comment: Diferente de arquivos executáveis, arquivos comuns como .jar nao tem ícone próprio (o mesmo vale para imagens, documentos de texto e tudo o mais que seja associado a outra aplicação - mesmo aqueles que tem miniaturas de arquivos são tratados por uma extensão do OS). O que mostra o ícone é o sistema operacional, dependendo da associação de arquivos. No Windows isto fica no registro, e costuma ser vinculado ao instalar uma aplicação que "assuma" aquela extensão, ou quando você faz um "abrir com..." e escolhe um programa em definitivo.

Comment: De um .jar apenas não é possível, ou você troca de todos os .jars ou de nenhum. Uma opção é criar um executável que inicializa o seu .jar, ou criar um atalho para ele.

Comment: Existe esse software que converte .jar para .exe e você consegue definir uma imagem para o arquivo gerado. http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/ , não dou exemplo porque não trabalho com java, mas fica a dica.

Comment: Veja [essa minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/205794/28595). Tem uma dica de como criar um executável personalizado com ícone e tudo mais :)

Comment: Tem uma opção chamada **icon**, é só passar o caminho de algum arquivo.icon pra ele. -> https://a.fsdn.com/con/app/proj/launch4j/screenshots/basicSettings.PNG/1

Comment: @diegofm o aplicativo diz que o output file está sem nada. Como proceder?

Comment: Veja o print, todos os campos ali devem ser informados. output é o caminho do executavel a ser criado, clica na pastinha.

Comment: @GuilhermePassos https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGATu.jpg

Comment: @diegofm aparece uma mensagem dizendo: Specify minimum JRE bersion and/or bundled JRE path. Como proceder?

Comment: Você quer q a aplicacao execute no mínimo em qual versão de máquina virtual(jre) do java?  Isso é pra fins de compatibilidade. Por exemplo, se você usar recursos do Java 8, precisa ter Java 8 como versão minima, senão não irá funcionar.

Comment: @GuilhermePassos clica na aba JRE, tem um campo la chamado min JRE.

Comment: Qual a versão da JRE que você vai definir como minima?

Comment: @diegofm 1.8.0_121, essa

Comment: @GuilhermePassos depois de preencher todos os campos da primeira aba e inserir essa versão minima no campo que mostrei, clica no simbolo de engrenagem no topo da tela. O launch vai pedir pra você salvar um xml, que é configuração que você acabou de definir nele. Após isso, o seu app.exe estará no local que você informou em `output`

Comment: @GuilhermePassos se você não passar o `imagem.ico` nao vai atribuir icone. Não pode ser png nem jpg, é obrigatório ser `.ico`. E se for um jar executado em modo texto, tambem está perdendo tempo, não vai funcionar se não for executado em linha de comando.

Comment: @diegofm o primeiro problema do ícone, você acabou de resolver

Comment: @diegofm agora, como assim executado em modo texto? Qual a diferença de linha de comando

Comment: @GuilhermePassos modo de texto é quando ele executa numa janelinha de console da IDE, totalmente em texto. Se não tiver interface grafica, é bobeira criar exe.

Comment: @diegofm, acabei de formatar a imagem para ico e resolveu tudo, agora está funcionando perfeitamente. Muito obrigado pela ajuda, e acima de tudo pela paciência!

Comment: @GuilhermePassos sem problemas. :)